# В btrfs, запись логов через strace грузит ЦП на 30%, почему так происходит?

Tags: linux, fs

При этом логи весят где-то 50 кб. Как так выходит, что 50 кб так загружают цп? Сжатие в этой ФС, перезаписывает файл полностью, или сжатие поблоковое, и затрагивает лишь блок в который попадает запись?

Comment: в вопросе крайне сильные и голословные утверждения... тесты на основе которых ты сделал такие выводы и конфигурацию системы в студию...

Comment: Пусть ответят у кого проблемы сходные.